# Change "My Account" to "Sign in/Sign out" option in header in magento rwd theme?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, header, rwd

I want to change "My Account" to "Sign in/Sign out" option in header in the upper right corner.

In C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\customer.xml

I changed

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

to

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Sign In/Sign Out</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>Sign In/Sign Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Still not displaying Sign In/Sign Out....

So how to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
<default>
<customer_logged_in>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
<customer_logged_out>
   <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>Sign In/Sign Out</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>Sign In/Sign Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_out>
```

Try that.. the idea is to put it inside this tag "customer_logged_in" and "customer_logged_out"

Comment: i did change in 

C:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\html\header.phtml

<div class="account-cart-wrapper">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('customer')->getAccountUrl(); ?>" data-target-element="#header-account" class="skip-link skip-account">
                    
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Sign In'); ?></span>
     <span class="icon"></span>
                </a>

Comment: Now how to make sign in to sign out when user do sign in?

Comment: \app\design\frontend\ranch\default\layout\customer.xml

In "<customer_logged_in>" change label Lot out to Sign Out 

I think it's very straight forward

Ps: accept this answer if it's answered your  question

Comment: when i will open homepage, Sign in is showing. When i click on it, there is dropdown -> clicked Log in button. After that i wants to make sign in to sign out in header. But it is not showing... only showing sign in ..

Comment: Can u show me your customer.xml or local.xml

Comment: <div class="account-cart-wrapper">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('customer')->getAccountUrl(); ?>" data-target-element="#header-account" class="skip-link skip-account">
<span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Sign In'); ?></span><span class="icon"></span>
                </a>

Comment: after sign in,  sign out is not showing...

Comment: Your current customer.xml, i think we don't need to change the phtml